# With Snapshot enabled android Emulator fails

Tags: android, emulation, snapshot

Two days ago I installed all the Android SDK updates. Earlier I had 2.2 API 8, Revision 2. After the upgrade I enabled snapshot - I am not able to start the emulator with Snapshot enabled. I get this message (in red) in the **Console**
    NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state ftruncate failed: Invalid argument

I get this message in **logcat** almost every 5 seconds
03-03 19:45:38.008: WARN/MountService(59): Waiting too long for mReady!

the trace before this message appears is  shown below

```
03-03 19:39:56.633: INFO/SystemServer(59): Mount Service  
03-03 19:39:56.672: INFO/SystemServer(59): Notification Manager  
03-03 19:39:56.722: INFO/SystemServer(59): Device Storage Monitor  
03-03 19:39:56.752: ERROR/VoldConnector(59): No connection to daemon  
03-03 19:39:56.752: ERROR/VoldConnector(59): java.lang.IllegalStateException  
03-03 19:39:56.752: ERROR/VoldConnector(59):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:191)  
03-03 19:39:56.752: ERROR/VoldConnector(59):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:178)  
03-03 19:39:56.752: ERROR/VoldConnector(59):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.doCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:213)  
03-03 19:39:56.752: ERROR/VoldConnector(59):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.doListCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:258)  
03-03 19:39:56.752: ERROR/VoldConnector(59):     at com.android.server.MountService$2.run(MountService.java:425)  
03-03 19:39:56.783: INFO/SystemServer(59): Location Manager  
03-03 19:39:56.793: INFO/SystemServer(59): Search Service  
03-03 19:39:56.802: INFO/SystemServer(59): DropBox Service
```

Can anyone please tell me what could be wrong with my setup? I am attaching a screenshot of Installed packages.

[image]

The emulator does not start I have to kill it and restart eclipse with with snapshot disabled.
http://tools.android.com/recent/emulatorsnapshots

With Snapshot disabled - here is what logcat looks like

```
03-04 04:17:41.387: INFO/SystemServer(73): Device Storage Monitor  
03-04 04:17:41.398: INFO/PackageManager(73): Updating external media status from unmounted to unmounted  
03-04 04:17:41.407: DEBUG/VoldCmdListener(29): share status ums  
03-04 04:17:41.457: INFO/SystemServer(73): Location Manager
```

The AVD platform is 2.2/API 8
Thank you

@Greg
Here are the details for  AVD
[image]

Comment: Can you post the AVD options that were used to create this? Screenres, sd card, etc?

Comment: I can't repeat this issue on my setup. I used all the same parameters. What system are you running on? I used XP 32bit, Eclipse Helios SR1

Comment: @spidy: XP 32bit SP3 - Galileo -   Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.2.2.20100217-2310 epp.package.jee       Eclipse Platform 3.5.2.M20100211-1343 org.eclipse.platform.ide

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the sdcard and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

here's what i did and result:
in AVD manager, edit the avd, there is Emulation Options, deselect the Snapshot option.(i forget why i selected it, but i guess the snap shot is missing, and causes the error.) and it works. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by space characters within the snapshot name. Try editing the name to ensure no space characters.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.